# Ubuntu 18.04 Dual boot Windows 10 fails to boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

Right,
So I am having a complete nightmare with this. I have as far as I know exhausted all the help I can get from browsing the forums.

Laptop: Porsche Design Book One

OEM OS: Windows 10

Ubuntu: 18.04

Boot Mode: UEFI

I freed up around 270gb of space on the primary drive /dev/nvme0n1.
Installed ubuntu basically without any complex partitioning.

Grub just always boots up to command. If I hit F12 to show boot menu, it shows:

- Windows Boot Manager (INTEL SSPD....)
- Grub (INTEL SSPD....)
- BIOS Setup

If I boot using Windows Boot Manager (which is default boot anyway) it just goes straight to windows. If I select Grub I get command line.

I had a small breakthrough where at command line I can get Ubuntu to boot, using the following:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,gpt5)
grub> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/nvme0n1p5
grub> initrd /initrd.img
grub> boot
```

This boots absolutely fine.

I have:

- Disabled fast boot in windows
- Disabled secure boot in the bios
- Added an entry using bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\grub\shimx64.efi
- Ran update-grub and grub-install
- Used boot repair

None of this works

The dump of boot repair is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Qg6Ktfpfzw/. Which should give a pretty good insight into the setup.

If anybody could help me get Linux booting properly that would be great. I have done this on multiple computers before and never had a problem with it dual booting. It must just be this weird laptop. Or I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi
```

I downloaded on 2 Oct 2018, Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS AMD64. And I  found the grubx64.efi in the `\EFI\boot` directory on my USB drive. I got no grub screen as well until I added the command I mentioned.